# Speech to text with OpenAI Whisper in Unity acts weird on Android phone

Tags: unity-game-engine, text-to-speech, openai-api, whisper

I am testing 'Speech to text' provided by OpenQI Whisper. It works perfectly fine in Unity Editor, but it acts weird on Android phone. It show wrong text that I didn't say. For example, I say 'hello there?' and AI shows 'Okay'. Not even close. It happens every time I try.

I am new to AI or microphone stuff. Is there any differences to use the microphone between laptop(Macbook pro) and Galaxy S21? Any advice will be so appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: How did you implement it?